# MyBatis Error: Invalid bound statement (not found)

Tags: mybatis

Here is the stack trace when I try to execute a simple query using MyBatis:

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.ppcredit.gypsophila.mapper.GypsophilaVarsStatisticsMapper.selectBySql
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:225)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:48)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MapperProxy.java:65)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:58)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.selectBySql(Unknown Source)
```

Here is a method from my class:

```
/**
 * use the sql to query result
 *
 * @param sql
 * @return
 */
List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> selectBySql(String sql, Map<String, Object> parms);
```

In this case, need want to execute SQL statement directly, the sql as below:

```
SELECT VELOCITY_VARS FROM PPC_GYPSOPHILA_VARS_STATISTICS WHERE SCENARIO_ID=#{scenarioId} and TACTIC_ID=#{flowId} and CREATE_USER=#{userId}
```

all parameters of sql can be found in `Map<String, Object> parms`

I've done some research, but none of the solutions have worked for me. My Mapper class seems have some problems, but i dont know what's wrong.
Does anyone have an idea what's wrong here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suppose that public interface GypsophilaVarsStatisticsMapper implements selectBySQL, in a correct way. I assumed you are import annotations if you are using it by:

```
import com.ppcredit.gypsophila.mapper.entity.GypsophilaVarsStatisti‌​cs;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.*;
public interface GypsophilaVarsStatisticsMapper { 
    List<GypsophilaVarsStatistics> selectBySQL(String sql,Map parameters);
      /**your code**/
```

I am going to suppose likewise, that you have a class (let's call it test) whose scope allows to call GypsophilaVarsStatisticsMapper Interface (in other case import). That would i do is the folloging:

```
import com.ppcredit.gypsophila.mapper.entity.GypsophilaVarsStatisti‌​cs; 

public class Test { 
           public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

              Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("SqlMapConfig.xml");
              SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);       
              SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
              session.getConfiguration().addMapper(GypsophilaVarsStatisticsMapper.class);

              GypsophilaVarsStatisticsMapper mapper = session.getMapper(GypsophilaVarsStatisticsMapper.class); 

              sql_string = 'SELECT VELOCITY_VARS FROM PPC_GYPSOPHILA_VARS_STATISTICS WHERE SCENARIO_ID=#{scenarioId} and TACTIC_ID=#{flowId} and CREATE_USER=#{userId}'
              Map<String,Object) params = getParams() /* Your params */
              List<GypsophilaVarsStatistics> result = mapper.selectBySQL(sql_string, params)
```

I suppose than you not are using MyBatis with a dependency injection framework like Spring. In this case SqlSessionFactory is supplied by this framework.

Comment: No, I dont create mybatis-config.xml, i only use the annotation to config

Comment: Using annotations, Ok. I think out that you have a GypsophilaVarsStatisticsMapper.class which is mapped to your SqlSession by `session.getConfiguration().addMapper(GypsophilaVarsStatisticsMapper.class);` It's difficult to figure what's happening without complete stacktrace and source code.

Comment: Thanks, source code as below:
import com.ppcredit.gypsophila.mapper.entity.GypsophilaVarsStatistics;

public interface GypsophilaVarsStatisticsMapper {

    
    List<GypsophilaVarsStatistics> selectBySQL(String sql,Map parameters);

The Mapper is an interface, cant get the SqlSession. i need to pass the original sql statement to that method.
Do you have any idea?